# insert edges in faces- CGAL error: assertion violation

Tags: c++, qt-creator, combinatorics, cgal

I'm creating an application using qt creator which read .off files as CGAL::Linear_cell_complex_for_combinatorial_map and preview it I want to make operations on the read mesh such as removing edge and restore it .

**it shows the following error :**
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CGAL::Assertion_exception'
  what():  CGAL ERROR: assertion violation!
Expr: is_insertable_cell_1_in_cell_2(adart1, adart2)

I searched about it but I cannot get an useful solution

```
 QWidget* viewer ;
   std::string filename;
   Dart_handle dh3;
 LCC_3 lcc;
   QMainWindow qWin;
  CGAL::DefaultColorFunctorLCC fcolor;

void MainWindow ::insertCell()
{
      dh3=lcc.insert_cell_1_in_cell_2(lcc.darts().begin(), lcc.darts().end());
    CGAL_assertion( lcc.is_valid() );

    lcc.display_characteristics(std::cout) << ", valid=" <<
      lcc.is_valid() << std::endl;

    setCentralWidget( new CGAL::SimpleLCCViewerQt<LCC_3, CGAL::DefaultColorFunctorLCC>(&qWin ,
                      lcc,
                      "Basic LCC Viewer",
                      false,
                       fcolor ) );
    show();
}

 void MainWindow ::removeCell()
 {
    CGAL_assertion( (lcc.is_removable<2>(dh3)) );
    lcc.remove_cell<1>(dh3);
    CGAL_assertion( lcc.is_valid() );
     lcc.display_characteristics(std::cout) << ", valid="
                      << lcc.is_valid() << std::endl;
}
```

any help? or usefull links to simplify mesh or removing vertices , edges or faces ? 
I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

To insert an edge in a face, cf the doc [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Combinatorial_map/classGenericMap.html#af052e3f6c70a2d691a2bdbccfa9c3908). For a face in a volume, the doc is [there](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Combinatorial_map/classGenericMap.html#ae07843054741ac7462b4e90dc945a28b). You can also have a look at the example [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Combinatorial_map/index.html#Combinatorial_mapHighLevelOperations).

The important thing to understand is when you add an edge into a face, you need to say where to insert the edge. This is the reason why you give two precise darts. This is similar when you want to insert a face into a volume: you need to give a sequence of darts which is a cycle of edges in the volume.

Comment: @gdaminad I tried the following but no insertion is done :
  dh1= lcc.darts().begin() ;
       dh2=lcc.darts().end();

  if (lcc.is_insertable_cell_1_in_cell_2( dh1, dh2) ){
      lcc.insert_cell_1_in_cell_2( dh1,dh2);
 }
     lcc.display_characteristics(std::cout) << ", valid=" <<
       lcc.is_valid() << std::endl;